# Puppeteer is not considering the value of localStorage if I set the value using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to convert an html web page into a pdf file by using puppeteer. I am storing a value in localStorage and getting the value back to change the font size of h1. The problem is if I store the value in localStorage via eventListeners, puppeteer seems to be ignoring the localStorage value and converting the web page with the default font-size. But if I store value in localStorage with calling the setItem method outside of any eventlisteners, puppeteer is considering those localstorage values and converting the page with new font-size. I want it to work when I call the setItem method inside of eventListeners.

I have tried changing the event listener to 'beforeprint' but I got the same results.

```js
let link = document.querySelector('a');
let heading = document.querySelector('h1');
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let fSize = localStorage.getItem('size');
  heading.style.fontSize = `${fSize}px`
})
localStorage.setItem('size', 500); // If I call it here puppeteer is considering the localStorage value

link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  localStorage.setItem('size', 500); //but if I call it here it is not considering the localStorage value
})
```

```html
<h1>A Heading</h1>
<a href="/download">download</a>
```

```js
//puppeteer code snippet

let printPDF = async() => {
  const filePath = path.resolve('./file.pdf')
  const fileUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    headless: true
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    await page.goto(fileUrl)
    await page.pdf({
      format: 'A4',
      path: filePath,
      printBackground: true
    });

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
  }
}

app
  .route('/')
  .get(getIndexPage);

app.route('/download').get((req, res) => {
  printPDF().then(() => {
    res.sendFile('./downloadPage.html', {
      root: __dirname
    })
  }).catch(e => console.log(e))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer opens an entirely new browser when you run it and that browser doesn't have the same localStorage data as the browser that you used to click your link. Your browser and the browser puppeteer spins up each have their own localStorage.

The reason it worked in the first case is that that code ran every time the page was loaded, *even when the puppeteer browser loaded it*.

Any changes you make to a web page after it loads (like a click event), won't be there when puppeteer loads the page on its own a few seconds later. It's like a refresh.

Could you just pass the data you need from the client to the server?

Comment: It is still not considering the localstorage value. The event block seems to be working fine. It is completing all the tasks before navigating to /download as I can see the changed value in the chrome dev tools.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question before. Check my edited answer.

Comment: It makes sense now. I think I could use the fetch method to post the data to the server. And use some templating engine to change the font size using that data. Thank you, now I can resume my work.